# Verifiy if a mouse is defective

Tags: mouse, events

I have only Linux machines (Ubuntu 22.04) and I've just received a 3D Connexion CadMouse Pro that officially does not support Linux. But I guess it's about the control software, as an HID mouse it should at least move the pointer.

I'm afraid it may be defective. I'm looking for a way to understand if the mouse itself is working or not.

Here some debugging I made:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0723 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL827L SD/MMC/MS Flash Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 1ea7:002c SHARKOON Technologies GmbH USB Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0a5c:2148 Broadcom Corp. BCM92046DG-CL1ROM Bluetooth 2.1 Adapter
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 256f:c656 3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04d9:a061 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. USB Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 256f:c635 3Dconnexion SpaceMouse Compact

$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 0a5c:4503 Mouse                       id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Gaming Mouse                          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Gaming Mouse Consumer Control         id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro                  id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard System Control               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard Consumer Control             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 0a5c:4502                             id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Gaming Mouse                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Gaming Mouse System Control           id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Gaming Mouse Consumer Control         id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]

[10193.373908] usb 3-4.5: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[10193.488391] usb 3-4.5: New USB device found, idVendor=256f, idProduct=c656, bcdDevice= 1.08
[10193.488397] usb 3-4.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10193.488399] usb 3-4.5: Product: CadMouse Pro
[10193.488400] usb 3-4.5: Manufacturer: 3Dconnexion
[10193.497577] input: 3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.5/3-4.5:1.0/0003:256F:C656.0015/input/input47
[10193.497760] hid-generic 0003:256F:C656.0015: input,hidraw8: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.5/input0
[10193.499613] input: 3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.5/3-4.5:1.1/0003:256F:C656.0016/input/input48
[10193.499687] hid-generic 0003:256F:C656.0016: input,hiddev2,hidraw9: USB HID v1.11 Multi-Axis Controller [3Dconnexion CadMouse Pro] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.5/input1

$ ls -l /dev/input/by-id/
totale 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 09:21 usb-04d9_USB_Keyboard-event-if01 -> ../event5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 09:21 usb-04d9_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 mar 17 09:21 usb-0a5c_4502-event-kbd -> ../event12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 mar 17 09:21 usb-0a5c_4503-event-mouse -> ../event13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 09:21 usb-0a5c_4503-mouse -> ../mouse1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 12:00 usb-1ea7_USB_Gaming_Mouse-event-if02 -> ../event9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 12:00 usb-1ea7_USB_Gaming_Mouse-event-kbd -> ../event7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 12:00 usb-1ea7_USB_Gaming_Mouse-if01-event-mouse -> ../event8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 12:00 usb-1ea7_USB_Gaming_Mouse-if01-mouse -> ../mouse0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 mar 17 12:10 usb-3Dconnexion_CadMouse_Pro-event-if01 -> ../event24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 mar 17 12:10 usb-3Dconnexion_CadMouse_Pro-event-mouse -> ../event23
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 12:10 usb-3Dconnexion_CadMouse_Pro-mouse -> ../mouse2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 mar 17 09:21 usb-3Dconnexion_SpaceMouse_Compact-event-if00 -> ../event3
```

Hence it seems it recognizes my mouse on `/dev/input/mouse2` and `/dev/input/event23` / `/dev/input/event24`.

I also tried to `cat` those files while moving the mouse, but there is no output. Instead if I `sudo cat /dev/input/mouse0` (the mouse that I'm using right now) I see some output.

Can I assume the mouse is not working at all?
Or is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I would try taking it to a friend's house and plugging it into their Windows, just to be sure.

Comment: @terdon that's a reasonable hint, and I'm going to follow it, but I want to better learn Ubuntu

Comment: Sure, my point is that this won't help you learn whether the mouse's hardware is somehow weird and not supported by your system or if the mouse is indeed faulty and if you test it on a Windows machine you'll be able to confirm. If it is faulty, if it also doesn't work on Windows, there's nothing you can do. If it does work on Windows, then we know it's worth investigating and seeing if there's anything that can be done to get it to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: @terdon got the point, but the questions is: should a working mouse output something on `/etc/event/mouse*`? Or is there a reason why this may not happen (a part of a hardware failure) ?

Comment: When you say you got no output, were you moving the mouse at the time? You will only see output if there is an "event" such as moving or clicking.

Comment: @terdon yes of course I move it. In fact I said moving my other mouse will output something on the other `event` file

Comment: Run `evtest` on the input device to see if there are events, but a device like this might need to sent some configuration or even firmware to work even a little bit like a mouse.

Comment: Well, [this page](https://3dconnexion.com/uk/supported-operating-systems/) shows the mouse is actually supported on Linux (if it's supported by one distribution, it will be supported by others, at worst you might need to install a driver), and the mouse is correctly recognized by name by your system, so this is looking more and more like a hardware problem.

Comment: @terdon sorry, but that page shows it's supported by Windows and Mac, *not* by Linux

Comment: Sorry, sorry, I thought that was a page that was specific to your mouse model and I now realize that the "hardware" column in each section lists which mice are actually supported. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the suggestion of user @meuh I tried to run:

`sudo evtest`

selecting the `event` file for my mouse.
The output was:

> This device is grabbed by another process.
> No events are available to evtest while the
> other grab is active.

Hence I issued:

```
$ sudo fuser -v /dev/input/event8
                     UTENTE      PID ACCESSO COMANDO
/dev/input/event8:   root       1405 F.... spacenavd
```

`spacenavd` is the driver for the 3D navigation device (you can see it in my `ls -l /dev/input/by-id/` output above). Stopping this service, the mouse started to work.

Bottom line: the mouse is functional, but there's a bug in the driver of the 3D Connexion SpaceMouse that prevents the CadMouse to work.